# laravel project deploy on 000webhost

Tags: php, laravel

**for the first time it was showing this error:**

Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0". You are running 7.2.31. in /storage/ssd1/034/19216034/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24

**after changing the PHP version on 000webhost now it's showing this error:**

Warning: require(/storage/ssd1/034/19216034/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd1/034/19216034/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 55

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/storage/ssd1/034/19216034/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /storage/ssd1/034/19216034/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 55

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is your question ? what is not clear in "Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0". You are running 7.2.31" did you run `composer install` after you changed the version ?

Comment: Please don't use 000webhost. They store passwords in plaintext.

Comment: I was trying to deploy my laravel project on 000webhost, then I show this error

Answer (score -1):

It seems you should check your bootstrap file address in your index.php